# dragula - Drag from one container to any cells of a table

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dragula

I'm using dragula in my application, I wonder if this library supports my scenario or not, Drag form this container:

```
<ul class="users-list clearfix" id="user_drag">
    <li class="user-info">
        <div class="user-info-for-match">
            <img src="/user/userOne.png" />
        </div>
        <a class="users-list-name" href="#">User One</a>
        <span class="users-list-date">
            Last recently
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="user-info">
        <div class="user-info-for-match">
            <img src="/user/userTwo.png" />
        </div>
        <a class="users-list-name" href="#">User Two</a>
        <span class="users-list-date">
            Last recently
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Drop in any of these cells with class `.drop_here`:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class='drop_here'>User 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class='drop_here'>User 2</td>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>
```

I want to drag any li (user) from container `user_drag` to any cell with class `drop_here`

But on `drop_here` container I just want user's name (content of `a` tag in container `user_drag`) to be dropped not the whole markup

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to capture 'drop' event and then fiddle the DOM like you need to?